# Load kmeans model, centroids and labels with cpickle

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, k-means

l stuck to load my kmeans model parameters. l used pickle to save and load my model as follow :

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2000).fit(examples)
distances = np.column_stack([np.sum((examples - center)**2, axis=1)**0.5 for center in kmeans.cluster_centers_])
np.savetxt('/data/distances.csv',distances,delimiter=",")
filename ='/model/k-2000.sav'
pickle.dump(KMeans, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

and l load the model as follow :

```
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

now l would like to get centroids and labels as follow :

```
loaded_model.cluster_centers_
```

l get the following error :

```
AttributeError: type object 'KMeans' has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'
```

Comment: `n_clusters` looks quite large to me. Is it possible that `KMeans` has simply failed to produce a result and, in consequence that, `cluster_centers_` is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the class not the instance 
    `pickle.dump(KMeans, open(filename, 'wb'))`
should be 
   `pickle.dump(kmeans, open(filename, 'wb'))`